# How to fill a select with markers from switched Leaflet layer groups

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have two layer groups on my leaflet map.

```
var firstMarkerLayer = L.geoJson(firstGroup, {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
  }
});

var secondMarkerLayer = L.geoJson(secondGroup, {
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);
  }
});

var overlays = {
  "first" : firstMarkerLayer,
  "second" : secondMarkerLayer
};
```

Also I have a code, that selects markers on my first layer from drop down list and shows corresponding tooltips.

```
var selector = L.control({
  position: 'topleft'
});

selector.onAdd = function(map) {
  var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'mySelector');
  div.innerHTML = '<select id = "marker_select"><option value = "init">(places)</option></select>';
  return div;
};

selector.addTo(map);

firstMarkerLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
  var optionElement = document.createElement("option");
  optionElement.innerHTML = layer.feature.properties.name;
  optionElement.value = layer._leaflet_id;
  L.DomUtil.get("marker_select").appendChild(optionElement);
});

var marker_select = L.DomUtil.get("marker_select");

L.DomEvent.addListener(marker_select, 'click', function(e) {
  L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e);
});
L.DomEvent.addListener(marker_select, 'change', changeHandler);

function changeHandler(e) {
  if (e.target.value == "init") {
    map.closePopup();
  } else {
    firstMarkerLayer._layers[e.target.value].openPopup();
  }
}
```

But it works only with one layer. Can somebody suggest me how can I complete my code to realize all features with any of selected overlap layers?

It is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/anton9ov/y4o7oxbu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you want to fill your `select` with the name of all your markers, from overlay layer groups `firstMarkerLayer` and `secondMarkerLayer`, and that it opens the marker's popup when the appropriate overlay is selected through the Layers Control?

In that case, you would just need to repeat the step with `eachLayer` where you fill the `select` for `secondMarkerLayer`.

Within your `changeHandler` listener, you would need to check first to which layer group the selected layer (marker) id belongs to, then open its popup.

You could avoid having to look for the parent layer group by also adding your individual markers into a 3rd layer group (that you **do not** add to map, of course), just to benefit from the `.getLayer(id)` method.

Then just check whether the marker is on map or not, and open its popup.

```
var marker_select = L.DomUtil.get("marker_select");

var allMarkers = L.layerGroup();

function fillSelect(layer) {
  var optionElement = document.createElement("option");
  optionElement.innerHTML = layer.feature.properties.name;
  optionElement.value = L.stamp(layer);
  marker_select.appendChild(optionElement);
  allMarkers.addLayer(layer);
}

firstMarkerLayer.eachLayer(fillSelect);
secondMarkerLayer.eachLayer(fillSelect);

function changeHandler(e) {
  if (e.target.value == "init") {
    map.closePopup();
  } else {
    var layer = allMarkers.getLayer(e.target.value);
    if (map.hasLayer(layer)) {
      layer.openPopup();
    }
  }
}
```

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y4o7oxbu/15/

---

EDIT:

As for changing the content of the `select` input as well, so that it lists only the markers of the layer groups on map (the one selected through Layers Control), you would simply need to listen to [`"baselayerchange"` event](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers-baselayerchange), empty the `select` input and fill it back with `fillSelect`.

```js
map.on ('baselayerchange', function (eventLayer) {
  var selectedLayer = eventLayer.layer;
  marker_select.innerHTML = '<option value = "init">(places)</option>';
  selectedLayer.eachLayer(fillSelect);
});
```

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/toj5wyt6/24/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also need to fill my `select` only with relevant `options`, i.e. only `firstPlace` and `secondPlace` should be in `select` when I choose the first layer. In the case above all markers collect in `allMarkers` and remain there independently of selected layer. Could you tell me, how to fill `select` only with corresponding `options`?

Comment: Listen to map's [`"baselayerchange"` event](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers-baselayerchange) to empty your `select` and fill it back with the selected layer group markers.

Comment: I'm very new in javaScript and Leaflet, that's why I have one more question about `baselayerchange`. I added some code with that and `options` began to come into the `select` according to selected layer. But they remain in the drop down menu, if I change the layer. Could you tell me please how can I take it away from my `select`? The code: http://jsfiddle.net/anton9ov/toj5wyt6/

Comment: I will put that in an edit at the bottom of the above answer. Next time, please fill up a new question.